# Access Denied when accessing Azure Key vault from Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

My requirement is to use the Secret keys which are stored in Azure Key vault, use the application configuration setting of Azure Function to get the Key, eg.@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=)

I get AccessToKeyVaultDenied Status in Azure Function, what permission should i provide for the function to fetch keys from vault.

Comment: Maybe you can try to give the 'Owner' Role assignment to your function app in keyvault Access Control and make sure you dont have a firewall&Virtual Network in keyvault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the `Get` secret permission on this policy.

There is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault) about granting your app access to Key Vault.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was able grant get access to my azure function within the Access policy inside Azure vault.